# Custom LDIF to CSV AWK Program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have this custom LDIFtoCSV AWK program (which looks ugly because of the null handling it does but it works fine)

```
BEGIN {
  sn = ""
  uid = ""
  UserStatus = ""
  BusinessPersonAccount = ""
}
/^sn:/ {sn=$0} {if(sn == "" || sn == "sn:")sn="sn: "}
/^uid:/ {uid=$0} {if(uid == "" || uid == "uid:")uid="uid: "}
/^UserStatus:/ {UserStatus =$0} {if(UserStatus == "" || UserStatus == "UserStatus :")UserStatus ="UserStatus : "}
/^BusinessPersonAccount:/ {BusinessPersonAccount =$0} {if(BusinessPersonAccount == "" || BusinessPersonAccount == "BusinessPersonAccount :")BusinessPersonAccount ="BusinessPersonAccount : "}
/^dn/{
  if(uid != "uid: ") printf("%s,%s,%s,%s",sn,uid,UserStatus,BusinessPersonAccount)
  sn = ""
  uid = ""
  UserStatus = ""
  BusinessPersonAccount = ""
}
END {
  if(uid != "uid: ") printf("%s,%s,%s,%s",sn,uid,UserStatus,BusinessPersonAccount)
}
```

Now the above AWK program was created based on the assumption that each record would have only one value for a particular attribute. But I got to know that few records like below also exist (having multiple values for the 'BusinessPersonAccount' attribute in this case):

```
dn: uid=SampleUid,ou=users,ou=External,dc=SampleDomain,dc=com
sn: SampleSn
UserStatus: 0
BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount1
BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount2
BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount3
uid: SampleUid
```

So the AWK programs currently returns:

```
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount3
```

But, for every user in the source LDIF data, I want the AWK program to generate a separate row for each value of this attribute instead of just printing out the last value.

Expected Output:

```
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount1
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount2
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount3
```

Could you please help me out ?

EDIT 1: I am basically looking for a change in the AWK program that will generate a new row for multiple-valued attributes for each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of `BusinessPersonAccount` entries determine the number of lines printed per user, it is best to use some kind of hash and array variables to store that info. Therefore, I suggest using perl instead of awk to process your data file (e.g. data.txt).
Here is one way:

```
cat data.txt | perl -ne '
chomp;
next if /^dn:/;
($key,$value) = split/:/;
$value =~ s/^\s+//;
$hash{$key} = $value;
push (@BPA, $value) if $key =~ /BusinessPersonAccount/;
if (/^uid:/) {
  foreach $bpa (@BPA) {
    print "sn: $hash{sn},uid: $hash{uid},UserStatus: $hash{UserStatus},BusinessPersonAccount: $bpa\n";
  }
  @BPA=();
};
'
```

Prints:

```
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount1
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount2
sn: SampleSn,uid: SampleUid,UserStatus: 0,BusinessPersonAccount: SampleAccount3
```

Comment: After a bit of modifications, I have achieved most of my requirement from this perl script. Since I am beginner at perl, could you please explain how does it determine the beginning and the end of each record (user) from the input LDIF data ? I am trying to implement base64 decoding for the encoded attributes (where the perl split/:/ fails as the encoded attributes have a double colon - '::' in LDIF). Could you please suggest a workaround for that ?